# filter 2 items of the same category (jquery)

Tags: jquery, select, filter, categories

This is what i want to ask a question about: 
http://berckmans-designs.nl/filternew/index1.php

I made this filter system with some help from here but the problem is: I can't select 2 items from the same category. ( so lets say i select 'wit' and 'zwart' from category 'kleur' )

Hopefully you guys can help me make this work.

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".series-selector-items > li").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        filterItems();
    });
});

function filterItems() {
    var classSelectors = $(".selected").map(function() {
        var cls = this.id.split('-');
        return '.'+cls.splice(2).join('-');
    }).toArray();

    //if no filter, show all
    if(!classSelectors.length){
        $('#items > li').show('slow');
    }

    $('#items > li').filter(classSelectors.join('')).show('slow');

    $('#items > li').not(function() {
        var self = this;
        var showThis = true;
        $.each(classSelectors, function(i,value) {
            if(!$(self).is(value)) {
                showThis = false;
            }
        });
        return showThis;
    }).hide('slow');
}
```

Comment: The `if(!$(self).is(value))` is false for each at one point, causing them both to be hidden.

Comment: question is, how can i fix this? my knwoledge of javascript/jquery is minimal so i really don't have a clue what i am doing

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. Check whether this helps you.

```
$(function() {
$(".series-selector-items > li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    filterItems();
});
});

function filterItems() {
var classSelectors = $(".selected").map(function() {
    var cls = this.id.split('-');
    return '.'+cls.splice(2).join('-');
}).toArray();

if(!classSelectors.length){
    $('#items > li').show('slow');
}
else {
$('#items > li').filter(classSelectors.join(', ')).show('slow');
$("#items > li").filter(":not(" + classSelectors.join(', ') + ")").hide('slow');
}
}
```

You can see the demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/pitchaip/huhbJ/1/

Comment: Nah mate, i need to filter everything out like if i select 'wit' and 'zwart' i should get only zwart and wit things but if i select fries, from the ras category, i need to only see the zwart and wit fries and not fjord and shetlander etc.